# [SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'179.43.156.163' (using password: YES)]

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

I know there are tons of topics on this argument on SO, but I think mine is different, or I just can't find it.
I use play framework 2.6, my application.conf looks like this:

```
default.db = {
  url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname"
  host="xxx.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com"
  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  username="root"
  password="password"
}
```

EDIT: some other part which might matter:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
play.http.secret.key="KVNU8u1lFSV_eNdfc=6oMnP@M<bH4YS<ZJqC5954p@S>=PiXwusl:vf>RWL2w_=D"
play.filters.hosts.allowed = ["."]
```

And I get continuously this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'19.345.16.16' (using password: YES)
```

after many attempts, I got this too:

```
SQLTransientConnectionException: ec2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1000ms.]
```

Why is it trying to connect with an empty user?
I tried already without "" and many other combinations..

EDIT: I made it connect with an empty field ('') user, so allowing users of type ''@'%', but I still need to figure out why slick tries to connect with an anonymous user. Now the sensible part of the application.conf is:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db = {
  url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/metamusic"
  host="xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  username=aa_admin
  password="password"
  keepAliveConnection = true
  connectionPool = disabled
}
```

Comment: Post your complete `application.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

For the original problem:

`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'19.345.16.16' (using password: YES)`

I agree with nitin.sharma0180's answer that it sounds like an error with MySQL user privileges and/or the password getting lost in transition to your server hosting the DB. Try checking if the user you are using has explicit permissions over the database and tables or maybe it is something as simple as a wrong password due to character encoding.

If the previous does not work, then it would depend on how you are connecting to your database through Play 2.6 Framework. Are you using JPA, straight up JDBC or other? To answer this check your build.sbt, your application.conf and the Play 2 modules that are being imported into your project.

Comment: I'm using jdbc, and slick.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE USER '<<username>>'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY '<<password>>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '<<username>>'@'%%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Try logging into the MYSQL

Comment: mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'xxx_admin'@'%%'; ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: It works using "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'xxx_admin'@'localhost'"

Comment: but using this user it still gives the same as before

Comment: update: after cleaning and re-running everything it says access denied for that newly created user

Answer (score 0):

In the application config you posted, you have the username root. Assuming that is the database authentication credential, you likely have that set incorrectly.
The only time root should be used is by the system admin, on the localhost.

Once you have the correct DB username & password configured, your error should be eliminated.

The grant stuff posted previously is accurate, but again ... nobody uses 'root'.

Comment: I used root for the past 6 months, now I changed db on ec2 and all this happened.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at our own config, but things are a bit different :

```
db {
    default {
       username="root"
       password=""
       url="jdbc:mysql://......"
    }
}
```

Notice the default.db vs db.default.

Comment: Notice this: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database/conf/application.conf